# how to use foreach loop into another foreach loop to traverse two different datatables in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

Is it possible to use foreach loop within foreach loop to traverse through two different database tables to get result ?

I want to show product list that inserted by admin_1 to its users and customers ?
and I keep products and users in two different tables. I'm using an admin_id to to distinguish products and users.
But I didn't get that how to get exact result.
Any help is appreciated.

here is my code :

```
<?php if (!empty($products)) { ?>
                    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>

                        <?php if((($this->session->userdata('user_id')) == ($product->id_admin)) || (userdata('department') == 0 )) { ?>
```

Comment: Yes possible.But the code and info you provided is not enough to help u.

Comment: please give any general example to do that. Because I entered that I code and nothing more I'm done in that code.

Comment: `print_r($products)` post your output.

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 14 [id_admin] => 7 [title] => Array [icon] => e44277435e318a7aa8b0c4d7169bfc2b.jpg [description] => Array [price] => 123.00 [link] => [sort_order] => 0 ))bool(true)

Comment: This is a really bad question.

Comment: I think you should use an SQL join for the two tables, thus only one query result to iterate thru.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is always using **UNION** if you want to combine the results of two different tables. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Here is a simple UNION example for your case:

```
<?php

public function retrieve_products_users_by_username($this_user) { // place this function into your model
    $this->db->where('username',$this_user);
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query_for_this_user = $this->db->get('users'); // whatever table you store the admin_1
    $this_user_id = $query_for_this_user->row_array()['id'];

    $this->db->select('products.id_admin as id_admin ,products.title as column1, products.icon as column2, products.descrption as column3 ...');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $products_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $this->db->select('users.id_admin as id_admin ,users.username as column1, users.profile_picture as column2, users.address as column3 ...');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $users_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM (' . $products_query . ' UNION ' . $users_query . ') AS u WHERE u.id_admin='.$this_user_id);
    return $query->result_array();
}

?>
```

I wrote this function with limited amount of information that you have provided in your question and comments. It could be a little bit different in reality, according the your table column names etc.

Anyway when you fully prepared this function in your model, you can call it from your controller like this:

```
<?php

$this->data['results'] = $this->YOURMODELNAME_model->retrieve_products_users_by_username('admin_1');

?>
```

As I said **UNION** is your solution. **JOIN** isn't your solution because:

- **JOIN** simply concatenates two table **horizontally**
- **UNION** simply concatenates two table **vertically**